# Find best machine learning for predicting category of products

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification

I have a dataframe that contains product and in this dataframe I have some features like: brand, `cat1`, `cat2`, `cat3`, `city`, `desc`, `image_count`, `mileage`, `price`, `title`, `year`.
The goal is predicting category of products. I have 1 billion training data and important features for prediction are title and description that are text type.
I like to know what algorithm is best for my prediction? I'm a beginner in machine learning and confused among different algorithms. Thanks

Comment: If you share some data we can come to a better answer for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an ideal problem for deep learning. Your outputs will be the categories and you can pick the 3 activations (categories) with the highest probabilities.

You will need to vectorize your description features, you can do this using one of these [techniques](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44617/multi-label-classification-for-text-messages-convert-text-to-numeric-vector/44619#44619).